# OpenGL Alpha blending with wrong color

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to create a simple ray tracer. I have a perspective view which shows the rays visibly for debugging purposes.

In my example screenshot below I have a single white sphere to be raytraced and a green sphere representing the eye.

Rays are drawn as lines with

```
glLineWidth(10.0f)
```

If a ray misses the sphere it is given color

```
glColor4ub(100,100,100,100);
```

in my initialization code I have the following:

```
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_SRC_ALPHA);
```

You can see in the screen shot that for some reason, the rays passing between the perspective view point and the sphere are being color blended with the axis line behind the sphere, rather than with the sphere itself.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!!

Comment: I edited to include your screenshot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it a possibility you cast those rays before you draw the sphere?

Then if Z-buffer is enabled, the sphere's fragments simply won't be rendered, as those parts of rays are closer. When you are drawing something semi-transparent (using blending), you should watch the order you draw things carefully.

In fact I think you cannot use Z-buffer in any sensible way together with ray-tracing process. You'll have to track Z-order manually. While we are at it OpenGL might not be the best API to visualize ray-tracing process. (It will do so possibly much slower than pure software ray-tracer)

Comment: Well I'll be... just changing the order of my drawing code is all it took; I had no idea that could effect things so much!! Thank you sir! You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Just to clear up my intent for the curious. The actual ray tracing is fully independent of the OpenGL drawing. I have just thrown in a 3d perspective view to help me debug while I get my ray tracer working. It just shows the rays and a copy of the raytraced image textured onto a quad in front of the raytracer eye point.

Comment: @puddlesofjoy: any chance you could edit the question and add the result after this fix?  It might be instructive for people to see what your intended result looked like.  Not a biggie - just a suggestion.  Glad this worked out!

Answer (score 2):

1. You dont need the `glAlphaFunc`, disable it.
2. Light rays should be blended by adding to the buffer: `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)` (for premultiplied alpha, which you chose.
3. Turn off depth buffer writing (**not testing**) when rendering the rays: `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)`
4. Render the rays last.

Answer (score 2):

AlphaTest is only for discarding fragments - not for blending them.  Check [the spec](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version1.1/glspec1.1/node96.html)
By using it, you are telling OpenGL that you want it to throw away the pixels instead of drawing them, so you won't can any transparent blending.  The most common blending function is
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  You can also check out the [OpenGL Transparency FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm).